# Derivative of indicator function involving time

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Take the function $f : \mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(t,x) = \mathbb{1}_{[1-t,2-t]}(x) $$ I am trying to figure out what $\partial_{t}f$ should be in the distributional sense.

My idea is to use the definition of the derivative $$\partial_{t}f = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(t+h,x) - f(t,x)}{h}. $$ using that I got $\partial_{t}f = \delta(x+t-1) - \delta(x+t-2)$. I am not sure if my answer is correct since the function is a multivariable function and I know that the derivative is often defined differently to what I gave above.

If we were to find $\partial_{x}f$ then it would be $\delta(x+t-1) - \delta(x+t-2)$ and I am fine  with this. We can just fix time and treat it like a single variable function. But when time is involved I become unsure since we can't just fix $x$ and treat it as a single variable function..

Comment: If your intention is to figure out what $\partial_t f$ is in the distributional sense, why don't you compute the distributional derivative by pairing with a test function rather than heuristically finding difference quotients that might mislead you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $H(t)=1_{\{t\ge 0\}}$ denote the Heaviside function, the fundamental relation is
$$
\frac{d H}{dt}(t)=\delta(t).$$
Now,
$$
1_{[1-t, 2-t]}(x)=H(t+x-1)H(-t-x+2).$$
Differentiating we get
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dt}1_{[1-t, 2-t]}(x)&=\delta(t+x-1)H(-t-x+2) - H(t+x-1)\delta(-t-x+2)\\ &=\delta(t+x-1)-\delta(-t-x+2),
\end{split}$$
which is the result we wanted.

*Remark*. In the last identity we have used the property
$$
f(t)\delta(t-a)=f(a)\delta(t-a); $$
so, for example,
$$\delta(t+x-1)H(-t-x+2)=\delta(t+x-1)H(-1+2)=\delta(t+x-1), $$
since $H(1)=1$.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of doing it like this

Comment: Thank Olivier Heaviside. He invented this kind of calculus, inspiring Dirac. Then Schwarz finally rigorized it